# Transpose, inverse of permutation matrix is itself?

Tags: matrices

It appears to me that the transpose and the inverse of a permutation matrix is itself.
Am I correct?

Comment: No. $$\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\cr0&0&1&0\cr1&0&0&0\cr0&0&0&1\cr}$$

Comment: Thanks, Gerry! That is a very good example!

Answer (score 2):

The correct statement should be: the transpose and inverse of a permutation matrix coincide, i.e. if $P$ is a permutation matrix, then $P^{-1}=P^T$.